# navigation title custom

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to add a custom navigation title to my SwiftUI project. I have a few tabs and I’m getting a weird bug. For every tab I am getting the same navigation title of "Home" and I can’t seem to change it or remove it. I’m not sure why there is even a title for each tab as I never added one. I have tried using `.navigationTitle("my title")` to edit the tab title. This is not working though, anyone know a fix? I will attach some code below.

```
        TabView(){
             FeedView()
                .navigationTitle("hustles")
                 .tabItem {
                     Image(systemName: "h.circle")
                 }
             JobsView()
                 .tabItem {
                     Image(systemName: "j.circle")
                 }
          }
```

```
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
            
            tweetsView
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .navigationTitle("Profile")
    }
```

Comment: Make sure the navigation view/stack is inside each tab and not outside the tabview

Comment: @loremipsum thanks that seems to have worked by allowing to me to add a navigation title. But for some reason this new title Im adding goes below another navigation title which is "Home." Im not sure how to get ride of this "Home" title above my custom nav title. Also this Home title appears on all my tabs, I also did not add this in anywhere. Its kind of like a defualt title. Any idea on how to get ride of it?

Comment: You have to remove the navigation view above the tabview

Answer (score 0):

just add navigation view inside each tab item and then add it the specific view inside the navigation view